# Operations on data table with variable column name

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to perform operations on a `data.table`'s column that is passed as a variable.

Here is a toy example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(2)
DT <- data.table(replicate(3, runif(4)))
> DT
          V1        V2        V3
1: 0.1848823 0.9438393 0.4680185
2: 0.7023740 0.9434750 0.5499837
3: 0.5733263 0.1291590 0.5526741
4: 0.1680519 0.8334488 0.2388948
```

Say the column of interest is passed as the value of a variable:

```
> print(target.column <- sample(colnames(DT), 1))
[1] "V3"
```

So I would like to perform some operation on column `V3`, say, flooring the value at 0.5 for simplicity. I have successfully made this work by using the dreaded `paste`, `parse` and `eval`:

```
> eval(parse(text = paste0("DT[", target.column, " < 0.5, ", target.column, " := 0.5, ]")))
          V1        V2        V3
1: 0.1848823 0.9438393 0.5000000
2: 0.7023740 0.9434750 0.5499837
3: 0.5733263 0.1291590 0.5526741
4: 0.1680519 0.8334488 0.5000000
```

But have been unsuccessful in my other attempts:

```
> DT[eval(target.column) < 0.5, eval(target.column) := 0.5, ]
          V1        V2        V3
1: 0.1848823 0.9438393 0.4680185
2: 0.7023740 0.9434750 0.5499837
3: 0.5733263 0.1291590 0.5526741
4: 0.1680519 0.8334488 0.2388948
> DT[as.name(target.column) < 0.5, as.name(target.column) := 0.5, ]
          V1        V2        V3
1: 0.1848823 0.9438393 0.4680185
2: 0.7023740 0.9434750 0.5499837
3: 0.5733263 0.1291590 0.5526741
4: 0.1680519 0.8334488 0.2388948
> DT[deparse(substitute(target.column)) < 0.5, deparse(substitute(target.column)) := 0.5, ]
          V1        V2        V3
1: 0.1848823 0.9438393 0.4680185
2: 0.7023740 0.9434750 0.5499837
3: 0.5733263 0.1291590 0.5526741
4: 0.1680519 0.8334488 0.2388948
```

I have looked for solutions on SO and the ol' interweb have not been able to find anything useful... is there a "data.table" way to do this?

Comment: FYI, you don't need `print` there. The parentheses alone will print the result: `(target.column <- sample(colnames(DT), 1))`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27897404/1191259 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11680579/1191259

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
DT[ get(target.column) < .5, (target.column) := .5]
```

which gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

A modification of your code will be to use `eval(as.symbol(` or `eval(as.name(`

```
 DT[ eval(as.symbol(target.column)) < .5, (target.column):= .5][]
 #         V1        V2        V3
 #1: 0.1848823 0.9438393 0.5000000
 #2: 0.7023740 0.9434750 0.5499837
 #3: 0.5733263 0.1291590 0.5526741
 #4: 0.1680519 0.8334488 0.5000000
```